# Trying to use the MS Band from an android Service

Tags: microsoft-band

Im trying to write a simple app for some running friends of mine. Basiclly they run for long distance and along the way they want to use the band to mark a location. Click on a tile on the band, click on a button that says "Mark" They do not want to worry about the application running or not. So I assume app will be closed on Android phones. I got my prototype working, kind-of. The main issue I'm having is app is closed!

BandPendingResult addTile(***Activity var1***, BandTile var2) throws BandIOException;

Add type first parameter requires an activity. I am trying to build this as a service that when a button on the Band is pressed "wakes" up the service, gets the GPS location and sends it to the server.  Activity is not a service.

When the service starts I have tried to remember the activity its bound to, but when the application get closed the activity is killed off and BOOM!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Tile requires an Activity because it requires user confirmation (i.e. it displays UI).  However, you should not be adding the Tile as part of your service; it should be done (just once) as part of the application's setup/settings flow.  The service should only be concerned with responding to the Tile events.